# Is there any way to list all the attributes in unlang of FreeRadius?

Tags: freeradius

I'm attempting to make some authorization logic by unlang in the the `post-auth` section of my FreeRadius server. I'm wondering if there is a way to show all the attributes I could access in my unlang code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [default policies](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/policy.d/debug) included in the server (versions >= 3.x.x) to do just that.

```
post-auth {
    debug_all
    ...
}
```

Should do what you need.

Comment: Any alternative for version 2.2.9? I can't upgrade the FreeRadius right now.

Comment: No, there's no equivalent in the v2.x.x series.  I can't back port the code because the v2.x.x branch is frozen.